# Continuing to read in from string after using a limiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My Question probably does not explain the issue well at all but what I'm experiencing is that I'm able to get the first line of a string for a "box" as shown in the sample here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_ifaCiEZgtcVUx3c2c1VWs2NEE

here's my main code as it is now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class LineBreaker
{
 private String line;
 private int breaker;

public LineBreaker()
{
this("",0);
}

 public LineBreaker(String s, int b)
  {
   line = s;
   breaker = b;
  }

public void setLineBreaker(String s, int b)
{
    line = s;
    breaker = b;
}

public String getLine()
{
    return line;
}

public String getLineBreaker()
{
    String box ="";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
    //scan.useRadix(breaker);
    //while (scan.hasNext()){
        for(int i = 0; i < breaker; i++){
        box += scan.next();

    }box += "\n";
    //}

    return box;
}

public String toString()
{
    return line + "\n" + getLineBreaker();
}
}
```

And it's associated runner class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Lab12f
 {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
  {
   LineBreaker test = new LineBreaker("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9", 4);
    out.println(test);

    test.setLineBreaker("t h e b i g b a d w o l f h a d b i g e a r s a n d t e e t h", 2);
    out.println(test);

    test.setLineBreaker("a c o m p u t e r s c i e n c e p r o g r a m", 7);
    out.println(test  );

    test.setLineBreaker("i a m s a m i a m", 2);
    out.println(test);

}
}
```

currently my output is looking like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

1234

t h e b i g b a d w o l f h a d b i g e a r s a n d t e e t h

th

a c o m p u t e r s c i e n c e p r o g r a m

acomput

i a m s a m i a m

ia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this block of code here:

```
public String getLineBreaker() {
  String box ="";
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
  //scan.useRadix(breaker);
  //while (scan.hasNext()){
      for(int i = 0; i < breaker; i++){
      box += scan.next();
  
  }box += "\n";
  //}
}
```

You never tell the program to keep reading from the line after reading to the first break.

#### EDIT

Ok.  Don't use `scan.useRadix(breaker)`.  That doesn't apply--`useRadix()` tells the compiler what base to parse numbers in.

You were on the right track with the `while` loop.  If you uncomment it, though, it throws an error.  This is when the scanner is looking for the next element in the line, but there isn't one.  Check if there's an element remaining before reading it...

And a tip from personal experience:  Meeting with your professor when you have a question can make a world of difference...  This **is** a place to ask questions (I'm not saying you are wrong to do so), but I will say that your professor knows you better than I do.

Comment: That's where I figured the issue was but no matter what I try, it'll either throw an error (not a scanner error) or it'll just give the same output

Comment: Hmmm... Well, I'm not 100% familiar with using Scanner for this--I would typically use manipulation at the character level.  I will say that `scan.useRadix(r)` just tells the scanner to interpret numbers in base r.  I'll respond again if I can find a way to use the scanner...

Comment: So if using `while(scan.hasNext()){...` is trying to find out if there is another bit of the string but it doesn't read it as I'd expect because the string `line` has been terminated early, how's that worked around?

Comment: Let's say you have `breaker = 4`, and the remaining characters in the string are `abc`.  When you hit the while loop, you have a next character, so it proceeds to try and read 4 times.  Essentially, you're only checking if there's a next character every `breaker` characters.

Comment: right, I just can't think of how to tell the program to read 4, new line, read next 4, new line, read next 4, new line.....

Comment: `scan.next()` gives the next character.  Read the next character (if it exists) 4 times.  Then add a new line character (`'\n'`).  Repeat.

I don't really feel comfortable helping beyond that... (as it is a homework assignment)